# sql server getting specific data from XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

HI friends I have the following table in **sql server 2014**:

### Table [Product]

```
Serie,  Int (primary key column)
Name, varchar(100)
LeftMenu, xml
```

Here is an example of the XML in the LeftMenu column each row could have:

```
<menu>
<e>
<col>1</col>
<url>
/products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/general-info
</url>
<IDElement>General-Info
</IDElement>
</e>
<e>
<col>2</col>
<url>
/products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/parts
</url>
<IDElement>parts
</IDElement>
</e>
</menu>
```

The expected result is like the following

```
Serie | col | name
-------------------
1000  |  1  | parts
```

From a given Serie (the primary key), I want to get the value of the node `<col>` passing the value of the `<IDElement>`  tag.

It is like searching inside each `<IDElement>` in the XML and return the value of the `<col>` tag that matches that group of elements.

I am trying the following but somehow it is not working:

```
select p.serie, p.name,
pref.value('(col())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as MenuName,
from prodInfo p 
p.[left-menu].nodes('menu/e') as names  (pref)
WHERE  
pre.value('(IDElement())[1]', 'varchar(max)') == @IDElement
AND p.serie =@serie
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Other option my partner suggested is to do it as in old times and create a new table instead of using XML,  any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the expected result in table format

Comment: OK thank you, I've updated the question with the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented the WHERE to illustrate PARTS is Col 2, OR I completely misunderstood your requirements

```
Declare @YourTable table (Series int,Name varchar(100),LeftMenu xml)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1000,'Some Series Name','<menu><e><col>1</col><url>/products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/general-info</url><IDElement>General-Info</IDElement></e><e><col>2</col><url>/products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/parts</url><IDElement>parts</IDElement></e></menu>')

Declare @Fetch varchar(100) = 'Parts'

Select A.Series
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select  Col  = B.value('col[1]','int') 
                       ,Name = B.value('IDElement[1]','varchar(100)') 
                       ,URL  = B.value('url[1]','varchar(100)') 
                From LeftMenu.nodes('/menu') AS A(Grp)
                Cross Apply A.Grp.nodes('e') AS B(B)
                --Where  B.value('IDElement[1]','varchar(100)') = @Fetch
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Series  Col Name            URL
1000    1   General-Info    /products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/general-info
1000    2   parts           /products/pressure-relief/pressure-relief-valves/parts
```

Comment: the example return no values, I had to declare thexml variable, DECLARE @XML xml

Comment: @franko_camron Sorry, I made an edit  it should be From LeftMenu.nodes('/menu') AS A(Grp)

Comment: @franko_camron Updated.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thank you @john Cappelletti,  it throws an error Invalid column name 'LeftMenu', guess because it is out of scope

Comment: @franko_camron Runs clean here - new window and all.   What is the field name which contains your XML data